# Удаление ОС Linux

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu

Доброго времени суток. На ноутбуке стоит единственной операционной системой Linux Ubuntu. Решил её удалить и поставить Windows. Вот в чём вопрос. Как правильно удалить Linux? Поискал решения в интернете, где то пишут, что сначала надо отформатировать диски в формате ntfs, где то говорят, что можно сразу вставлять загрузочную флешку и при выборе место установки просто удалить разделы. Как будет правильней?

Comment: Удаляй разделы.

Comment: в каком виде у вас дистрибутив Windows?

Comment: Хороший вопрос! +1

Answer (score 3):

Рекомендую не ознакамливаться с этой статьёй, а просто форматировать диски во время установки Windows на соответствующем пункте.

https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/247804/how-to-remove-linux-and-install-windows-on-your-computer